# Read user input with New Line

Tags: unix

How do I put in read command with newline character?

Here is a sample code:

```
    read -p 'Enter account: ' acct
    echo "$account" > text.txt
```

Expected output:

```
    Enter account:
    123456
    654321
    777777
    888888
```

And if I will check text.txt file, the result must look like this:

```
    cat text.txt
    123456
    654321
    777777
    888888
```

Answer (score 0):

Your read fills the variable `acct`, not `account`. Output the right one:

```
read -p 'Enter account: ' acct
echo "$acct" > text.txt
```